# How to create a 2D-matrix out of my data for surf()?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 25000x3-matrix, with each row containing a x-, a y- and a z-value. Now I wanted to do a graphical plot out of these. But for using for example surf(Z) I have to use a mxn-matrix as Z with m equal the size of x and n equal the size of y. How can I reshape the matrix I have to the needed mxn-matrix? The problem is that my x- and y-values are no ints, but floats, so I assume that I have to do a interpolation first. Is that true? My data plotted with plot3 looks like:
[image]

Comment: This will depend on what data is actually in there. If you `plot3(A(:,1), A(:,2), A(:,3),'.')`, does it look like a function of `(x,y)`? (The MATLAB logo for example is, but a sphere isn't) You could upload this so we can have a look.

Comment: did you manage to make your randomly sorted data set into a grid?

Comment: Yes, but afaik I switched to python. Still have to check on this one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that your x- and y- values are not integers is not a problem at all. The real question is: are your (x,y) points forming a grid, or not ?

- If your points are forming a grid, then you have to reshape your columns to form m-by-n arrays. You may need to `sort` your data according to the first, then second column and then use the `reshape` function.
- If your points are not forming a grid, then you will have to make an interpolation. By chance the [scatterinterpolant class](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant-class.html) can nicely help you in doing so.

Comment: You mean, if my values are like X(i) = Y(i)? No, that is not the case.

Comment: By grid I mean: does your (x,y) pairs map all the possible pairs of a rectangular mesh ?

Comment: I don't know that. How can I check that? x and y are equally sized.

Comment: Well, if it is not designed for, there is little chance that it maps a mesh. Anyway to check this you can start by looking at the numler of elements of `unique(x)`, which we will call `u`, and of  `unique(y)`, which we will call `v`, and check that `u*v` is equal to the size of your initial array, _i.e._ 25000.

Comment: do you have any real code for making the random data set into a grid?

Comment: if the data doesn't form a grid, then is it not possible to use `surf`?

Comment: @Pinocchio As written in my answer, if the data doesn't form a grid you have to make an interpolation first in order to use `surf` or `mesh`, an the scatterinterpolant class is made for this. I have no generic code for this, it all depends on the nature of your data.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the data you are providing is neither given in a gridded way, nor is the point cloud clean. You could however try to do the following:

1. Project the point cloud onto the x-y plane
2. Triangulate those points
3. Give the points their original z-coordinate back.
4. Plot the surface using [`trisurf`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trisurf.html)

Here is a MATLAB code that does this:

```
%// Generate some points P
[X,Y] = ndgrid(0:30);
P = [X(:), Y(:), X(:).^2+Y(:)];
%%// Here the actual computation starts
[~,I] = unique(P(:,1:2),'rows'); %// Remove points with duplicate (x,y)-coords
P = P(I,:);
T = delaunay(P(:,1),P(:,2)); %// Triangulate the 2D-projection
surface = triangulation(T, P(:,1), P(:,2), P(:,3)); %// Project back to 3D
trisurf(surface); %// Plot
```

You may want to remove stray points first, though.

Comment: How can I determine if I have stray points or not? And when I use your code on my data, I get a quite strange result, which does not look like my first image.

Comment: @arc_lupus: The points that are a lot higher than your other points I would consider as *stray* points.  But that is an inherit limitation, that you need smooth surface data to plot a surface. If your data is really noisy, you might just want to plot the surface using `plot3` or `scatter3`.

Comment: @arc_lupus: What you are trying to achieve is not *creating a 2d matrix out of my data for surf*, but you will actually want to do [*surface reconstruction of  your point cloud*](https://www.google.at/webhp?#safe=off&q=surface+reconstruction+point+cloud), which is a much harder task.

Comment: @arc_lupus: Yes, that's correct. It depends of course what you want to do with this data, but if you are not content with a point-cloud-plot, but want a smooth surface, you either have to do manual clean-up or dig into a harder problem.